# How is it possible to know if an application is using some Google Play Services API’s e.g. Maps, Location Services, Google+, Ads, Drive etc

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, robotium

Also if it’s known that some play service API is used, how to test it to know if it’s working correctly. Is it possible to use some instrumentation techniques (Junit,Robotium etc.) to test play services API’s .

Note that the application is installed in phone from Android Market and we don’t have access to the source code of that application.

I am not sure if it’s possible or not a but I am trying to find out the way but not able to succeed as of now.

I found that we can parse AndroidManifest.xml of application to get the meta-data tag defining google play services lib but how to know about particular Service Api usage in that application.

I can think of about getting details in log cat  of the application if play service produce the specific usage logs . But the problem is that that logs would be generated only at particular instance in the application and we may not aware of that instance.

Another approach I can think about if somehow we can parse network data using some android  API or third-party API.

Comment: Can you please give me the reason why someone has given negative point?

Comment: I suspect it is because they cannot think of a legitimate purpose for doing this, i haven't voted either way but maybe add what you are trying to achieve by knowing this?

Comment: I am actually doing research to make automation script/tool to test the google play services for downloaded Apps(APK's) form Android Market.I am sure its a genuine question for my research work.

Answer (score 0):

If you decompile source code and code is minified (secured), I think the only way is to try to "sniff" http traffic in/out from Android phone with for example Wireshark software

Comment: Dear Sime,Thanks for your answer.Can you please provide more details on this .How can I know if some service is used and its working fine if I just "sniff" the http traffic?

Comment: For example if you see in wireshark that android device is sending GET request for url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles you can therefore conclude that app is using Google Directions API... i don't see another way to know what services is app using if source code isn't avaible

Comment: Thanks Sime, I will check other details.